# How would i separate this into 2 different functions and still make it work?

Tags: python, list, function

How would I make one function open the file and read it and the other function do the math to calculate the leap year and work?

I know how to make it read the file and still be a function but i don't know how to make it work with the math.

```
def open_txt():
with open("all_years.txt","r") as f:
    f_contents = f.read()
    print(f_contents)
open_txt()
```

---

My code supposed to take a list and calculates whether or not the variable/numbers are 4 digit leap years.
This is the list i was supposed to use.
https://pastebin.com/bENBWSyB

```
File_leapyears = open(input("What file do you want to use?: "), "r")
for line in File_leapyears:
    year_str = line[:4]
    if year_str.isdigit():
        Leap_year = int(year_str)
        if Leap_year % 4 == 0 and Leap_year % 100 != 0:
            print(Leap_year)
        if Leap_year % 100 == 0 and Leap_year % 400 == 0:
            print(Leap_year)
```

Comment: What is your question? You need to be more specific

Comment: assign f_contents to File_leapyears . That should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like:

```
def process(line):
    year_str = line[:4]
    if year_str.isdigit():
        Leap_year = int(year_str)
        if Leap_year % 4 == 0 and Leap_year % 100 != 0:
            return(Leap_year)
        if Leap_year % 100 == 0 and Leap_year % 400 == 0:
            return(Leap_year)
    return None

def read_file():
    File_leapyears = open(input("What file do you want to use?: "), "r")
    for line in File_leapyears:
        yes = process(line)
        if yes:
            print(yes)
```

Comment: yea somewhere along the lines of this.